# How to manage .Net's RCW COM object creation paramets (namely requested interface)?

Tags: com, interop, createinstance, rcw, iunknown

I'm using an external native COM component in my C# .NET application.

This COM DLL doesn't have a type library, so I had to write the interop code myself, and having include/idl files I did it like TlbImp does.
But the worst thing is that the object creation fails with:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {40700425-0080-11D2-851F-00C04FC21759} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040111
```

The class is finally created if I use the native `CoCreateInstance` and specify `class_id` and one of the implemented interface IIDs.

As it turned out the problem lies in that the COM object's `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` doesn't support `IID_IUnknown` passed as the `riid` parameter, and therefore returns `CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE` (I identified it with disassembler and debugger). The component is MS SQL VDI.

Is there any way to force the .NET RCW to pass a different interface ID into the `CreateInstance` method rather than `IID_IUnknown`?
I searched the net a lot, but didn't find a solution for this.

As a workaround I'm using C++/CLI now to create the object, requesting the proper interface instead of `IID_IUnknown` for this purpose now; but I would like to have code in C#, because C++/CLI requires me to build a different DLL for each platform.

Thanks

Comment: Failing to respond to IUnknown from CoCreateInstance() is a bug.  Can you get the owners of the external library to fix it? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/26/96777.aspx

Comment: The owners are Microsoft, and since this bug has been existed for more than 10 years and taking into account that it doesn't block the component usage I don't think the patch will be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I repro.  Brr, painful.  You could pinvoke CoCreateInstance:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
[DllImport("ole32.dll", ExactSpelling=true, PreserveSig=false)]
public static extern object CoCreateInstance(ref Guid clsid, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkOuter, int context, ref Guid iid);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, Hans. It does the trick, and simple rapper will hide it. Though it would be nice to have something like (edit -- God, how to post a linefeed in comment? NBoth Enter and CtrlEnter presses Save button). ... something like:  [DefaultInterfaceGuid("XXXX-XXX-XXX")] or so.